# Variable length in a Matrix c++

Tags: c++

I'm using VS 2019.
In this code:

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Inserisci la dimensione della matrice:";
    int DIM;
    DIM = 2;
    cin >> DIM;
        int v[DIM][DIM];
    return 0;
}
```

I Don't understand why in:

```
int v[DIM][DIM];
```

I've this error:

*The expression must have a constant value. It is not possible to use the "DIM" variable value as a constant.*

Comment: Note that the post title must be in English too.

Comment: As the error says, `DIM` must be a constant (compile-time) value.

Comment: If you need a run time sized array, use a `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr`